# Array key and value in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have one array:

```
$array1=['0'=>'field_1','1'=>'field_2'];
```

My expect output result to my new array:

```
$newarray=['field_1'=>field1_val,'field_2'=>field2_val];
```

I try that code:

```
$newarray=array();
foreach($array1 as $value){
    $newarray[] = $value;
}
print_r($newarray);
```

But it's seem to be not working. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: so you are trying to crate new array with $array1 values as key?

Comment: @Aroon yes i want new array with $array1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$array1=['0'=>'field_1','1'=>'field_2'];
    $newarray=array();
    foreach($array1 as $value){
         $newarray[$value] = $value;
    }
    print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: @Rajes : is `field_1` and `field1_val` are same ?

Comment: Not the same i put value to field_1 key

Comment: but here key and value are same `$newarray[$value] = $value;`

Comment: @RishiRaut just an example bro

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$newarray=array();
    foreach($array1 as $value){
         $newarray[$value] = $value;
    }
```

You can also use **array_combine** :

array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values.

**Syntax:**

```
array_combine ($keys ,$values );
```

**Code:**

```
$newarray = array_combine($array1, $newarray);
```